# Excel If with 3 conditions if cells are blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

Cant seem to find a way to get this fully working. I have three columns A, B, C. If a cell in A is blank then it should show as "DMA" & if in B it should display " MSE Wall". Cells in C are a combination of A + B. Now usually there are other values in Cells A & B so only if either cell of A or B is blank, cell C should be "DMA MSE Wall".

Heres what i got :

```
=IF(F1256="",E1256 &"MSE WALL",E1256&" "&F1256)

The above code will only get the below results :

1) A is blank + B is blank = MSE Wall
2) A = DMA + B is blank = DMA MSE Wall
3) A is blank + B = MSE Wall = MSE Wall
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What is the E and F column in your formula? The question only speaks of A, B and C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think you need. If you copy the following in C1 (or change the `1`s to fit your needs for row number), then you should get

- "DMA MSE Wall" when A1 or B1 is blank
- a combination of A1 and B1 when both are populated. Note if you want to add a space between their content, you can do A1&" "&B1.

`=IF(OR(A1="", B1=""), "DMA MSE Wall", A1&B1)`